# pywinauto: Исключение вместо нажатия на кнопку

Tags: pywinauto

```
# Нахожу кнопку и получаю ButtonWrapper, здесь всё нормально происходит.
close_button = app['Button51'].wait(wait_for='exists ready', timeout=30)

# При попытке нажать на кнопку, получаю исключение NoPatternInterfaceError
close_button.click()
```

Вопрос: почему возникает исключение в данном случае и кнопка не нажимается?

Comment: Уточнение. Я пытаюсь автоматизировать управление 1С.

Comment: Предыдущие ответы помогли? Просто обычно ответы, решившие проблему, принято помечать как правильные (серый чек бокс слева от ответа работает для автора вопроса всегда, независимо от репутации).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что на стороне приложения не реализован InvokePattern (можно в Inspect.exe это увидеть в свойствах элемента в режиме UI Automation).

Можно попробовать ещё метод `.toggle()`, но это вряд ли поможет. Точно будет работать только метод `.click_input()`. Он делает настоящий клик мышью с перемещением курсора. `.invoke()` или `.click()` - не настоящий, но мог бы работать при залоченном экране, если б был реализован в приложении.